# Reciprocal basis of an ideal in $\mathcal{O}_K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Take $K/\mathbb{Q}$ a number field with ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$. Then an ideal $I \subset \mathcal{O}_K$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module of dimension $N = [K:\mathbb{Q}]$ with basis $(\alpha_1,\ldots, \alpha_N)$, that is :
$$I = \left\{ \sum_{n=1}^N m_n \alpha_n, m_n \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$$
Then we have $N$ complex embedding $\sigma_n : K \to \mathbb{C}$ (the Galois group of the normal closure) and we have the linear operator $\mathbb{C}^N \to \mathbb{C}^N$ :
$$T \quad :\quad  \begin{pmatrix} m_1\\ \vdots \\ m_N \end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} \sum_{n=1}^N m_n \sigma_1(\alpha_n)\\ \vdots \\ \sum_{n=1}^N m_n \sigma_N(\alpha_n) \end{pmatrix}$$
An important theorem is that $T^{-1}$ is of the form
$$T^{-1} \quad :\quad  \begin{pmatrix} m_1\\ \vdots \\ m_N \end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} \sum_{n=1}^N m_n \sigma_1(\frac{\beta_n}{\delta})\\ \vdots \\ \sum_{n=1}^N m_n  \sigma_N(\frac{\beta_n}{\delta}) \end{pmatrix}$$
$$\color{red}{\text{where }(\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_N)\text{ is a basis for the ideal }J \subset \mathcal{O}_K\text{ such that }IJ = (\delta)}$$

This is from this theorem that we get the [functional equation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/266360/functional-equation-dedekind-zeta-function/266643#266643) for the Dedekind zeta function $\zeta_K(s)$.

It is proven in [Hecke p.126](http://www.paris8.free.fr/Hecke-Lectures.on.the.theory.of.algebraic.numbers.pdf) and in [Neukrich p.218](http://www.paris8.free.fr/Algebraic%20Number%20Theory%20-%20Neukrich.pdf) but it is hard to follow their proof. In those books, for some $c \in K$, the notation for $\sigma_p(c)$ is $c^{(p)}$.

Can you **help understanding the main argument** ?

If it is easier, we can look first at $K$ totally real, so that $\sigma_n$ are real embeddings and $T$ is a linear operator $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: the Dedekind zeta function and the functional equation is studied in Corollary 5.11 in the Neukirch book and the proof does not explicitly mention $c^{(p)}$. What theorem on page 218 are you talking about?